# Conditional URL Rewrite Based on Page URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a conditional rewrite based on the URL of the page a link is on?

For example, if there was a Great Britain support page on an internationalized website:

```
www.site.com/gb/support-section/
```

and on the page was a link to a non-internationalized support article:

```
www.site.com/NOTSET/support-section/support-article.html
```

would there be a way to capture the `"gb"` from the hosting page and rewrite the destination support article to replace the `"NOSET"` with `"gb"` for a destination URL that looks like this:

```
www.site.com/gb/support-section/support-article.html
```

Comment: Bond, thank you for editing and formatting my post! Looks amazing. I look forward to learning the techniques you used to make it so clean and legible.